# How to share data between two browser windows

Tags: ajax, web-applications, browser, tabs, get

In my web application I get some data from server. Then if user want's to see this data visualized in great detail I want to open second browser window and do it there. The problem is with passing the data to be visualized. I don't want to make second request to server. So all I have now is to append this data to the URL to be opened in second window. This of course works but the URL look ugly and the amount of data is very limited. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a session-value. Save the data into the session when retrieving it from the server, and read it when you open the second browser tab.